# Prefab sorting layer wrongly displayed

Tags: unity, c#

I have a prefab 'WhiteSmoke' that should render on top of the other objects on my game view but instead it just stays behind. The sorting layer some you see on the image named 'smoke' is the top layer, changing it to default and keeping the big order in layer number does not solve the problem.

The canvas render mode is ScreenSpace-Overlay.

Have any idea what I'm missing here? I don't know what else to try.[image]

Comment: Particle effects are rendered in the 3D pipeline using the Z-buffer, not the 2D layering system that sprites use. Have you tried using multiple cameras to control the render order?

Comment: Can you point me where I can do that?

Comment: I recommend using Z values for distinctly seperate entities (player, enemy, etc), and for graphics within an entity use sorting layers as a tie breaker. This will just in general make things go smoother. Write down a table of z values an give them names to act like pseudo layers. Good luck friend!